# pillow でpngの読み込みエラー　cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x0000022C87254D68>

Tags: python, pillow

pillowでpngを読みこんでいるのですがエラーになります。
すべてのpng画像がエラーになるわけではなく、どうもメタタグ？を持っているものがエラーになっているようなのですが、どうしたら読めるでしょうか？

**エラーコード**

```
cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x0000022C87254D68>
```

使用画像
[image: 使用画像]

コードは以下です。

```
from PIL import Image
import io

with open("1578000644635.png", mode='rb') as f:
    data = f.read()
    img = Image.open( io.BytesIO( data)) #ここでエラーになる
```

Comment: iCCP chunk の内容が意図的に改変されているのかもしれないので、CRC チェックでエラーが発生する画像データは処理対象から外しておく方が無難かと思いますが、[Pillow/PngImagePlugin.py at 7.0.x](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/7.0.x/src/PIL/PngImagePlugin.py#L147) のコメントを読むと、`ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True` とすれば(事前に `from PIL import ImageFile` を実行しておく)、CRC チェックを行わなくなりますので読み込む事は可能です。

Comment: この画像のプロパティを見ると `icc:manufacturer: GIMP` となっているので GIMP の issue database で検索してみたところ、[GIMP created png with bad iCCP checksum from thumbnail (#2111) · Issues · GNOME / GIMP](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gimp/issues/2111) が見つかりました。現状での回避策は `Unchecking "Save Color Profile" while exporting` だそうです。。。

Comment: よくわかりました。ありがとうございます。